# How to apply a single ref to multiple elements like (<div>) ? React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I want to useRef() in 4 div elements, the divs controls the slider of some images.
the code is like this:

```
const slider = useRef()
const slideLeft = () => {slider.current.scrollLeft = slider.current.scrollLeft - 500};
const slideRight = () => {slider.current.scrollLeft = slider.current.scrollLeft + 500};


<>
 <BsChevronLeft onClick={slideLeft}/>
   <div ref={slider}>
   //Images mapped in here
  </div>
 <BsChevronRight onClick={slideRight}/>
     <BsChevronLeft onClick={slideLeft}/>
   <div ref={slider}>
   //Images mapped in here
  </div>
 <BsChevronRight onClick={slideRight}/>
     <BsChevronLeft onClick={slideLeft}/>
   <div ref={slider}>
   //Images mapped in here
  </div>
 <BsChevronRight onClick={slideRight}/>
     <BsChevronLeft onClick={slideLeft}/>
   <div ref={slider}>
   //Images mapped in here
  </div>
 <BsChevronRight onClick={slideRight}/>
</>
```

But whenever I click the first slider or div it only effects the last slider element,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, that is because `ref` is assigned after the element is created. 
You might want to create array of refs and scroll each `ref.current` in click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const slider = useRef([]);

const slideLeft = (index) => {slider.current[index].scrollLeft = slider.current.scrollLeft - 500};
const slideRight = (index) => {slider.current[index].scrollLeft = slider.current.scrollLeft + 500};


<>
 <BsChevronLeft onClick={()=>slideLeft(0)}/>
   <div ref={(el) => slider.current[0] = el}>
   //Images mapped in here
  </div>
 <BsChevronRight onClick={()=>slideLeft(0)}/>
     <BsChevronLeft onClick={slideLeft}/>
</>
```

We create an array of `ref` and we put each element in the array, then we simply refactor the event handler so it takes an argument that is the index of the element that triggered it.